# Dynamic model binding in trait function

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I have multiple Policy classes.

and these policies' `update, delete, restore` functions have the same logic evaluation which is to check if the authenticated user owns the resource.

For example, I have a **Post** and a **Comment** model.

Then for **PostPolicy** and **CommentPolicy**, both of their `update, delete, restore` functions will all have:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
}

public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
}

public function restore(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
}

// Also the same with CommentPolicy
```

With that, I might as well have a trait like this:

```
trait AuthorizableTrait
{
    public function authorize(User $user, Resource $resource)
    {
        return $user->id == $resource->user_id;
    }

}
```

So, my question is, is it possible to inject a dynamic instance of the current model inside the trait, for example, `Post` and `Comment` models now will become `Resource`? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple other ways to handle this too. In your trait, you can simply replace `Resource $resource` with `Model $model`. As long as your `Post.php`, `Comment.php` and `Resource.php` Models have are `class ... extends Model { ... }`, then it'll accept it:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait AuthorizableTrait {
  public function authorize(User $user, Model $model) {
    return $user->id == $model->user_id;
  }
}
```

If that is too "loose", and you don't want this available for all Models (i.e. in the possible case that not all Models have a `user_id` column), then you can use [Union Types](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types) (assuming you are on a compatible PHP version):

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models\Traits;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Resource;

trait AuthorizableTrait {
  public function authorize(User $user, Post|Comment|Resource $model) {
    return $user->id == $model->user_id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the type of the authorize function second parameter, I think it will be all right.

If you define the following function, without the `Resource` type:

```php
public function authorize(User $user, $resource)
```

You will be able to send everything you want in `$resource` (a post, a comment, etc.) and then the check will work... unless you always have a `user_id` attribute.

Comment: Yep, just found out too. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I decided to use PHPStan.

And the neon script requires that all function's parameter and return type must be specified.

Thus, I ended up specifying `Model` as `$resource`'s type.

```
public function authorize(User $user, Model $resource)
```

However, for some reason, in your use-case, `Model` is too generic.
Then you can do something [like what @TimLewis did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73818348/dynamic-model-binding-in-trait-function/73820528#73820528:%7E:text=%3C%3Fphp%20%0Anamespace%20App%5CModels%5CTraits%3B%0A%0Ause%20App%5CModels%5CPost%3B%0Ause%20App%5CModels%5CComment%3B%0Ause%20App%5CModels%5CResource%3B%0A%0Atrait%20AuthorizableTrait%20%7B%0A%20%20public%20function%20authorize(User%20%24user%2C%20Post%7CComment%7CResource%20%24model)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%24user%2D%3Eid%20%3D%3D%20%24model%2D%3Euser_id%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D:%7E:text=If%20that%20is%20too%20%22loose%22%2C%20and%20you%20don%27t%20want%20this%20available%20for%20all%20Models%20(i.e.%20in%20the%20possible%20case%20that%20not%20all%20Models%20have%20a%20user_id%20column)%2C%20then%20you%20can%20use%20Union%20Types%20(assuming%20you%20are%20on%20a%20compatible%20PHP%20version)%3A).

Comment: Didn't see that one. Sorry :). Will accept yours.

Comment: No worries, and it's not a big deal or anything; the important thing is you got it working. Cheers 